# Stripe do not add duplicate card nodejs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a payment system where a user can add multiple cards into application. Now there can be 4 AM Express cards or 10 Visa cards. However I want that when a user try to add an already added card then I should either just return the already added card saying that you've added the card or I can just update that already added card and then return it.

I went through some threads which say to check for fingerprint value and then just update the card but that doesn't make sense. Is there a more well defined way of doing this?

Here is how my cards gets added

```
public async addNewCard(customerId: string, newCardRequest: NewCardRequest): Promise<Card> {
    const stripeCustomerId = await this.getStripeCustomerId(customerId);
    if (!stripeCustomerId) {
      const stripeCustomer = await this.createStripeCustomer(customerId, newCardRequest.token, newCardRequest.nameOnCard);
      const card = await this.stripeApi.getCard(stripeCustomer.id, stripeCustomer.defaultPaymentMethodId);
      return Card.fromStripeCard(card);
    } else {
      const card = await this.stripeApi.addCard(stripeCustomerId, newCardRequest.token, { nameOnCard: newCardRequest.nameOnCard});
      return Card.fromStripeCard(card);
    }
  }
```

Stripe Client Service

```
  public async addCard(customerId: string, token: string, metadata?: Stripe.MetadataParam): Promise<Stripe.CustomerSource> {
    const sourceCreateParams: Stripe.CustomerSourceCreateParams = {
      source: token,
      metadata
    };
    return await this.stripeClient.customers.createSource(customerId, sourceCreateParams);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I went through some threads which say to check for fingerprint value and then just update the card but that doesn't make sense.

Checking the `fingerprint` is the correct way to approach this.  [Card objects in Stripe have a `fingerprint` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/object#card_object-fingerprint) for exactly this purpose (emphasis added):

> Uniquely identifies this particular card number. **You can use this attribute to check whether two customers who’ve signed up with you are using the same card number**, for example. For payment methods that tokenize card information (Apple Pay, Google Pay), the tokenized number might be provided instead of the underlying card number.

The way it works is if you have two or more Card objects in Stripe you can compare their `fingerprint` values and, if they match, those Card objects represent the same physical card.

So, in practical terms, you would do this:

1. Customer provides card information
2. You create a Card object in Stripe from that information
3. You compare the `fingerprint` of that Card with all of the other Cards that Customer has on file
4. If any existing `fingerprint` matches you let the Customer know you already have that card on file, otherwise you attach the new Card to the Customer